Spring-AMQP client does not recover after broker restart with idle channels getting stuck
So I have two microservices communicating through RabbitMQ, one of them sends RPC requests (using RabbitTemplate#sendAndReceive) to another. And I noticed that the app is not able to recover if the broker have been down for a few minutes.
Here's how I configure the connection factory and template:
    @Bean
    public AbstractConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        return new CachingConnectionFactory(createRabbitConnectionFactory(properties));
    }

    private static com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory createRabbitConnectionFactory(RabbitProperties properties) {
        final com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setHandshakeTimeout(60000);
        connectionFactory.setHost(properties.getHost());
        connectionFactory.setPort(properties.getPort());
        connectionFactory.setUsername(properties.getUsername());
        connectionFactory.setPassword(properties.getPassword());
        connectionFactory.setVirtualHost(properties.getVirtualhost());
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(
            AbstractConnectionFactory connectionFactory
    ) {
        final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
        rabbitTemplate.setReplyTimeout(10000);
        rabbitTemplate.setUserCorrelationId(true);
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }

And here's how I use RabbitTemplate:
final Message responseMessage = rabbitTemplate.sendAndReceive(
                routingKey,
                new Message(serializationService.toBytes(request),
                        MessagePropertiesBuilder
                                .newInstance()
                                .setContentType("my-content")
                                .setDeliveryMode(MessageDeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT)
                                .setCorrelationId(correlationData.getId())
                                .build()
                ),
                correlationData
        );

Then what I do is I put load on API method that triggers this RPC, then I turn off the broker and wait for a few minutes. Right after broker start I see a lot of logs like this:
SimpleConsumer [queue=amq.rabbitmq.reply-to, index=1091, consumerTag=amq.ctag-1DtEyYlNIMSNowMMsoPYNQ identity=57919ab] started

And then all new requests lead to an error:
org.springframework.amqp.AmqpResourceNotAvailableException: The channelMax limit is reached. Try later.

And in RabbitMQ interface I see that my connection has created 2047 channels, all of them are in idle state. Only app restart helps to fix the problem.
What do you think is happening here and how can I make the client automatically recover?
I use spring-boot-starter-amqp of version 2.7.5 (so spring-messaging 5.3.2 and spring-rabbit 2.4.7)
I've tried configuring channelCheckoutTimeout:
cachingConnectionFactory.setChannelCheckoutTimeout(10000);
cachingConnectionFactory.setChannelCacheSize(200);

But I just get another error and same situation:
org.springframework.amqp.AmqpTimeoutException: No available channels


Let's see if connectionFactory.setAutomaticRecoveryEnabled(false) helps somehow!
See more in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/amqp/connections.html#auto-recovery

@ArtemBilan I tried that, but I found out that CachingConnectionFactory actually disables this property anyway, so it doesn't change anything

OK. Any chances that you can upgrade to the latest supported version of Spring Boot and all its Spring dependencies? That spring-rabbit 2.4.7 is very out dated. Well, if you can share with us a simple project to let us to reproduce on our side, then it would be very helpful. Thanks

Unfortunately we cannot upgrade to the latest spring boot right away (we certainly do plan an upgrade, just going to take some time), but I'll try to prepare a simple project for reproducing the issue, thanks!

Hi @ArtemBilan, sorry, I had to take a break with this issue, but came back to it. Are you still up for checking out what's going on with that problem?
So I managed to create a small example that reproduces the issue, moreover, I updated the libraries version to the most recent ones and the issue still persists. I created a github repository with instructions for issue reproduction https://github.com/purrfessor/channel-leak-reproduction-spring-3

Looks like your problem is related to this issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/issues/2715. Please, consider to upgrade to Spring Boot 3.3.2. Unfortunately, the RabbitMQ restart does not perform properly for me on Windows, so I cannot reproduce it locally.

@ArtemBilan the repository that I provided above used 3.3.1, I just tried to upgrade to 3.3.2, and it didn't help (I commited the changes to the repository too).
Do you think that described behavior sounds like a bug if it reproduces on 3.3.2? Should I create an issue on spring-amqp github?

See my answer. That is is really not a bug. If we don't limit our cache in the application, it is going to use all the resource from the Broker eventually under the high concurrency. That is really an excepted behavior.

Found what is the problem.
Your application properties must have these:
spring:
  rabbitmq:
    host: localhost
    port: 5672
    username: guest
    password: guest
    cache:
      channel:
        checkout-timeout: 30s

Pay attention to that checkout-timeout: 30s.
This configures a limit on the opened channels from the CachingConnectionFactory:
/**
 * Sets the channel checkout timeout. When greater than 0, enables channel limiting
 * in that the {@link #channelCacheSize} becomes the total number of available channels per
 * connection rather than a simple cache size. Note that changing the {@link #channelCacheSize}
 * does not affect the limit on existing connection(s), invoke {@link #destroy()} to cause a
 * new connection to be created with the new limit.
 * <p>
 * Since 1.5.5, also applies to getting a connection when the cache mode is CONNECTION.
 * @param channelCheckoutTimeout the timeout in milliseconds; default 0 (channel limiting not enabled).
 * @since 1.4.2
 * @see #setConnectionLimit(int)
 */
public void setChannelCheckoutTimeout(long channelCheckoutTimeout) {

More info in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/amqp/connections.html#cachingconnectionfactory

Starting with version 1.4.2, the CachingConnectionFactory has a property called channelCheckoutTimeout. When this property is greater than zero, the channelCacheSize becomes a limit on the number of channels that can be created on a connection. If the limit is reached, calling threads block until a channel is available or this timeout is reached, in which case a AmqpTimeoutException is thrown.

You also can adjust that cache to what fits your expectations:
spring:
  rabbitmq:
    cache:
      channel:
        checkout-timeout: 30s
        size: 100

Note: host/port and credentials are just like that by default. So, no need in them in the application.yml.

Oh, you're right! I tried to do that on my 2.7.5 setup (on the original application), and it didn't help (I got the No available channels error that I mentioned in the original post), but on 3.3.2 it does help to set channel checkout timeout. Thank you very much for your help!
